# Get programs flags with a C program

Tags: c, unix, elf

I'm actually trying to get the flags of given by the objdump -s command through a C program. But I don't know where to look for them. For example here:

```
./my_objdump:     file format elf64-x86-64
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000112:
EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED
start address 0x00000000004006f0
```

I would like to know how to get:
flags 0x00000112:
EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED
in C.
Thank you

Comment: Why not just take a peek at what objdump does?  It's open source, right?

Comment: Running `strace` on Linux shows there are no system calls for this, but lots of `read`s and `lseek`s, so it's case of going into the binary file and interpreting the data directly. The parts you need will be in the source code, as above.

Comment: There's always [libELF](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Libelf) which allows you to read (and modify) ELF files.

Comment: Objdump use the BFD lib. I don't want to use any lib. I would like to hard code it to better understand how these flags works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know how to get: flags 0x00000112: EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED in C.

It's not clear from your question whether you don't know how to get the number `0x112`, or how to translate that number into `EXEC_P`, etc. [1]

The former is the value of e_flags in Elf64_Ehdr, which is right at the beginning of the file. That is, you read in `sizeof(struct Elf64_Ehdr)` bytes from offset `0` in the file into a buffer [2], and then:

```
printf("flags: 0x%x\n", ((struct Elf64_Ehdr *)buf)->e_flags);
```

The latter: `EXEC_P`, `HAS_SYMS`, etc. represent flags that `libbfd` uses internally, and have very little to do with actual `ELF` file. They are internal abstraction, and are (or should be) of very little interest to anybody.

But if you *really* care, the `D_PAGED` flag is set if the file has `e_phnum != 0`, i.e.

```
if (((struct Elf64_Ehdr *)buf)->e_phnum != 0) {
  printf("D_PAGED\n");
}
```

I am sure that `HAS_SYMS` is set if `.symtab` or `.dynsym` sections are present, etc.

[1] Note: contrary to what one might think, `EXEC_P` etc. flags are *not* derivable from `flags`.

[2] This would need obvious adjustment if your file is 32-bit ELF. It also assumes that you are looking at *native* ELF file. Examining big-endian ELF file  on little-endian machine (or vice versa) would require additional work.